# Function to return a record type or return nothing?

Tags: postgresql

I have written a function as below.

```
Create function tmp (in text, in text) 
returns setof record as $$ 
Declare rec record;
Begin
If $1 is not null and $2 is null then 
Select * into rec from test_tble where tmprec = $1;
Elsif $1 is not null and $2 is not null then 
Insert into test_tble values ($1,$2);
End if;
Return;
End; $$ language plpgsql;
```

My problem is the second condition.
First condition works well..
When second condition becomes true. I get insert the record but returns at last as below

$1 | $2

++++++

0 rows returned.

I don't want to return empty record with this column.
Can anyone help me to recover from this.

Comment: what return do you expect?..

Comment: You can use `INSERT ... RETURING *` to get the row which was inserted. -- But you don't have to use `plpgsql` for this: it can be achieved with [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). Also, the (somewhat) new [`UPSERT` (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) functionality seems similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: If the first condition satisfies.. I need to return a record else second condition satisfies , should insert a record in to tmp_tble and end

Comment: Using CTE also does the same right. My function inserts the record and returns zero rows.. I need to restrict returning after insert @pozs

Comment: so you want function to be able to return both `void` and `set of` based on id clause?..

Comment: Yes of course you are right @vao

Comment: I'm afraid you can't return both `void` and `set of` based on if clause

Comment: Can I do with raise after inserting?

Comment: do with raise what?..

Comment: Raise successful completion

Comment: please read this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: I have gone through the postgres 9.5 version , bit I couldn't find

Comment: If you find the solution, please share the topic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING

> If you declared the function to return void, a RETURN statement can be
>   used to exit the function early; but do not write an expression
>   following RETURN.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

> rettype
>
> The return data type (optionally schema-qualified). The return
>   type can be a base, composite, or domain type, or can reference the
>   type of a table column. Depending on the implementation language it
>   might also be allowed to specify "pseudotypes" such as cstring. If the
>   function is **not supposed to return a value, specify void** as the return
>   type.

(emphasis mine)

If you declare `return void`, you can't return a `set of` or any other return. Neither can you specify out parameter. So you either return something with function or return nothing. It is not controlled from function body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @vao

Comment: sure, hope it helped